# How to access data from an AWS RDS instance using Java

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created this DB in AWS
database-1.ccbrzww0e8op.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

I am trying to connect using this URL,

jdbc:mysql://database-1.ccbrzww0e8op.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/database-1

but I have this error:

```
[08S01]
    Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are writing your own Java Connection Class. To ensure that a Spring app can communicate with an Amazon RDS instance, you need to:

1. Ensure that your application has a Database Driver file. This can be accomplished by using the POM file.
2. Ensure that your RDS instance is configured to allow public access.
3. Ensure that you have setup your Inbound rules to let your development machine access the database. For information about setting up security group inbound rules, see [Controlling Access with Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html).

Once you perform these tasks, your Spring BOOT app can connect to the database and query data, as shown in this pic of a Spring BOOT app querying data from an RDS instance:

[image]